# Select next N rows after value

Tags: postgresql

I have table like this

| created_on | id | version | reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-08 17:13:30 | 34718 | 253 | accept |
| 2021-01-08 17:13:30 | 34718 | 253 | accept |
| 2021-01-08 17:13:25 | 34718 | 252 | Settle |
| 2021-01-08 17:13:25 | 34718 | 252 | Settle |
| 2021-01-08 17:13:25 | 34718 | 252 | Settle |
| 2021-01-08 17:11:13 | 34718 | 251 | offer |
| 2021-01-08 17:11:13 | 34718 | 251 | offer |
| 2021-01-08 17:10:26 | 34718 | 250 | Settle |
| 2021-01-08 17:10:26 | 34718 | 250 | Settle |
| 2021-01-08 17:10:26 | 34718 | 250 | Settle |
| 2021-01-08 17:10:24 | 34718 | 249 | Settle |

so I want to select next 5 rows after 'offer' value and set row number for each id

| row_id | created_on | id | version | reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2021-01-08 17:13:30 | 34718 | 253 | accept |
| 5 | 2021-01-08 17:13:30 | 34718 | 253 | accept |
| 4 | 2021-01-08 17:13:25 | 34718 | 252 | Settle |
| 3 | 2021-01-08 17:13:25 | 34718 | 252 | Settle |
| 2 | 2021-01-08 17:13:25 | 34718 | 252 | Settle |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 17:11:13 | 34718 | 251 | offer |

how to do it? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Having duplicates of the target complicates the issue somewhat and descending order does so also. Further the test data raises the question do you want the 5 after the target in all cases of just because there are only 5. Anyway the following should do.

```
with test_data( created_on, id, version,reason) as
     ( values ('2021-01-08 17:13:30'::timestamp, 34718, 253, 'accept')
            , ('2021-01-08 17:13:30'::timestamp, 34718, 253, 'accept')
            , ('2021-01-08 17:13:25'::timestamp, 34718, 252, 'Settle')
            , ('2021-01-08 17:13:25'::timestamp, 34718, 252, 'Settle')
            , ('2021-01-08 17:13:25'::timestamp, 34718, 252, 'Settle')
            , ('2021-01-08 17:11:13'::timestamp, 34718, 251, 'offer' )
            , ('2021-01-08 17:11:13'::timestamp, 34718, 251, 'offer' )
            , ('2021-01-08 17:10:26'::timestamp, 34718, 250, 'Settle')
            , ('2021-01-08 17:10:26'::timestamp, 34718, 250, 'Settle')
            , ('2021-01-08 17:10:26'::timestamp, 34718, 250, 'Settle')
            , ('2021-01-08 17:10:24'::timestamp, 34718, 249, 'Settle')
     ) 
select row_number(*) over() row_id, created_on, id, version,reason
  from (select created_on, id, version,reason
          from (select td.*, row_number() over( partition by reason order by created_on desc) rn  
                  from test_data td
                 where created_on >= (select min(created_on) from test_data where reason = 'offer')
              ) s1
          where (reason = 'offer' and rn = 1)
             or (reason != 'offer')
          order by created_on desc
          limit 6
       ) s2;
```